# Iam user not authorized to perform: firehose:CreateDeliveryStream on resource xxxx with an explicit deny

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to create a Firehose delivery stream from an EC2 micro instance.

AWS CLI is configured with the access keys of an IAM user ABC. This user has AWS policies attached with full access to firehose (policy copied below).

Still the stream creation fails with the error `AccessDeniedException: iam user ABC not authorized to perform: firehose:CreateDeliveryStream on resource xxxx with an explicit deny`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "firehose:*",
                "firehose:CreateDeliveryStream"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:firehose:us-east-1:<ACC_ID>:deliverystream/*",
                "arn:aws:firehose:us-east-1:<ACC_ID>:*",
                "arn:aws:firehose:*:<ACC_ID>:*",
                "arn:aws:firehose:*:<ACC_ID>:deliverystream/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I need to add more permissions to this IAM user to allow it to create delivery streams?

Comment: Do you have any other policy attached to this user and is it part of any group? looks there is explicit deny policy.

Comment: Double check the policies attached to the user (directly, or via groups/inline). Also, it is a bad idea to explicitly save user keys on EC2. Consider creating a role with the relevant firehose access and attach it to the instance.

Comment: @Abi: How do I use AWS CLI on EC2 using a role? All the steps mentioned in AWS Configure point to adding the keys to enable the CLI usage.

Comment: @Paladin - If you run CLI commands on an EC2 it picks up the permissions as provided to the instance role. You do not need to add keys (aws configure) to use it. On Amazon Linux instances it is pre-installed. More here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux-al2017.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cross checked all other policies attached to this user and apparently there was a Deny policy attached to this user which was explicitly denying the access. Removed this policy and it worked!